# Wordpress load function on specific page

Tags: wordpress, function

I'm trying to load some functions only on WooCommerce pages.

I've done that

```
if ( is_woocommerce() || is_cart() || is_checkout() || is_account_page() ) {
    
       require get_template_directory() . '/inc/wc_custom_cart.php';
       require get_template_directory() . '/inc/add_to_cart_ajax.php';
       require get_template_directory() . '/inc/wc_custom_product_field.php';
       require get_template_directory() . '/inc/wc_custom_form_checkout.php';
}
```

But it does not work, any idea ?

Comment: What's the output when you dump `require get_template_directory() . '/inc/wc_custom_cart.php';` ??

Comment: I tested, this method and looks like it should be working, the only way it could be causing an issue is you may be adding it multiple times which can cause `redeclare` issues.

Comment: When I put the condition, inc fields do not load. It works perfectly without...

Comment: Do this `var_dump(require get_template_directory() . '/inc/wc_custom_cart.php');` and visit one of the pages and see what does it dump.

Comment: Thanks, nothing occurs when I put condition. Without it return `[...]/wp-content/themes/my_theme/functions.php:89`

Comment: I've just tested with`(  $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] == '/shop/' )` and it works..

Comment: This means that you are calling your very early. Better to add it inside wp hook.